# Selecting the Values in the Excel Rows Depending on the selection of Check Box in the GUI using Python Tkinter

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have a Excel as Below

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Heading 1      |     Heading 2    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       Row1          |    Value 1       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       Row2          |    Value 2       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I am reading from excel and Showing the Values of Heading 1 in the GUI

[image: My GUI]

***When I click on submit Button , I need to read the value/text of the CheckBox depending on the selection of the CheckBox and Create XML by using Excel for only selected values***

***Problem is How can I only select the values in the Excel , depending on the selection of check Box. (But I know how to identify which check box is checked ). But how to relate to Excel is I am facing problem***

*Note: I Know how to create XML from excel 
      I know how to identify when submit is clicked*

GUI Code:

Config.Py

```
import tkinter as tk
import xlrd
import GetValueFromExcel
from GetValueFromExcel import ExcelValue
from array import array
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, Button
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

class UICreation():
    def __init__(self):
        print ("I m in __init__")
        self.tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)
        self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl)
        self.tab2 = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl)

    def tabcreation(self):
        print ("I M in Tab Creation")
        self.tabControl.add(self.tab1 , text="Tab1")
        #self.tabControl(self.tab1, text= t)
        ##self.tabControl(self.tab1, )
        self.tabControl.add(self.tab2, text="Tab2")
        self.tabControl.grid()

    def checkbox(self):
        print ("I M in checkBox")
        checkBox1 = Checkbutton(self.tab1, text=str(t[0]))
        checkBox2 = Checkbutton(self.tab1, text=str(t[1]))
        Checkbutton()
        checkBox1.grid()
        checkBox2.grid()

    def button(self):
        button = Button(self.tab1 , text="Submit", command=self.OnButtonClick)
        button.grid()

    def OnButtonClick(self):
        print ("I am Working")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ui = UICreation()
    ev = GetValueFromExcel.ExcelValue()
    ev.readExcelValue()
    t = ev.readExcelValue()
    print(t)
    ui.tabcreation()
    ui.checkbox()
    ui.button()
    #ev = readExcelValue()
    root.mainloop()
```

GetValueFromExcel.py

```
import xlrd

class ExcelValue():


    def __init__(self):
        self.wb=xlrd.open_workbook(r"C:\<FilePath>\Filename.xlsx")
       #self.ws=self.wb.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
        for sheet in self.wb.sheets():
            self.number_of_rows = sheet.nrows
            self.number_of_columns = sheet.ncols

    def readExcelValue(self):
        result_data = []
        row_data = []
        for sheet in self.wb.sheets():
            for curr_row in range(1, self.number_of_rows, 1):
                #for curr_col in range(0, self.number_of_columns , 1):
                    #data = sheet.cell_value(curr_row, curr_col)  # Read the data in the current cell
                    data = sheet.cell_value(curr_row, 0)
                #print(data)
                    row_data.append(data)
                    result_data.append(row_data)
        return result_data[1]
```

Comment: can you send a sample code?

Comment: @RaminNietzsche  sample code for which function ?

Comment: Your GUI code .

Comment: @RaminNietzsche Added to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the value to `Checkbutton` like this:

```
def checkbox(self):
    print ("I M in checkBox")
    checkBox1 = Checkbutton(self.tab1, text=str(t.keys()[0]), variable=t.values()[0])
    checkBox2 = Checkbutton(self.tab1, text=str(t.keys()[1]), variable=t.values()[1])
    Checkbutton()
    checkBox1.grid()
    checkBox2.grid()
```

and you must change `readExcelValue`, like below:

```
def readExcelValue(self):
    result_data = {}
    for sheet in self.wb.sheets():
        for curr_row in range(1, self.number_of_rows, 1):
                data = sheet.cell_value(curr_row, 0)
                value = sheet.cell_value(curr_row, 1)
                result_data[data] = value
    return result_data
```

Comment: But how can it be useful to select only those values in Excel to create XML ?

Comment: @sreevathsabr can you send the sample of your accepted XML output? :D

Comment: This helped allot